# how to like value to %field_value% in sql or codeigniter?

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a table named uri_table that contain:

## id, uri_segment

1, /dir_name/bla-bla-1/

2, /dir_name/bla-bla-2/

3, /dir_name/bla-bla-3/

I want to get the pure link that only contain until controller_name and the controller param are not included. but when I use $_SERVER['URI_SEGMENT'] it will get the controller param too.

so I can't do this code below to search in my model:

```
function check_uri()
{
    $this->db->like('uri_segment',$uri_segment,'after');
    $id = $this->db->get('uri_table')->row_array()['id'];
    return $id;
}
```

instead of:

```
function check_uri($request_uri=$_SERVER['URI_SEGMENT'])
{
    //trim controller param that is numeric
    for($i = strlen($request_uri)-1;$i > 0;$i--)
    {
        if(is_numeric($request_uri[$i]) || $request_uri[$i]=='/')
        {
           continue;
        }
        else
        {
            $request_uri =  substr($request_uri,0,$i+1);
            break;
        }
    }
    $this->db->where('uri_segment',$request_uri);
    $id = $this->db->get('uri_table')->row_array()['id'];
    return $id;
}
```

This is my code right now but is also can remove param that is number if the `$request_uri = '/dir_name/bla-bla-3/1/some_param/3'` it'll return $id null. What can I do to remove the param/get uri without controller param or how to compare the `$uri_segment` to `uri_segment ($this->db->like($uri_segment, '%uri_segment%'))?`

Comment: sorry for the confused explaination. I'm just a PHP and Codeigniter beginner and don't know what to do with that

Comment: are you want to extract  'bla-bla-1' form  the string?

Comment: I want to extract the /dir_name/bla-bla-1 instead of /dir_name/bla-bla-1/some_param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do one thing when you create a controller in that store the controller name like this:

```
class About extends CI_Controller {
    // MVC config
    var $PANEL = '';
    var $CONTROLLER = 'about';
    var $MODEL = 'mdl_about';
    var $TITLE = 'page title';
    var $LIST_PAGE_NAME = 'aboutus';

    function About() {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model($this->MODEL, 'model');
    }
    function index() {
        $this->load->view($this->LIST_PAGE_NAME);
    }
}
```

So that above controller, model, page title and view page can be use anywhere is related to that controller.

To display the variable value use like this:

```
echo $this->CONTROLLER;
```

Or you can try this:

```
$this->router->fetch_class(); //for controller
$this->router->fetch_method(); //for method
```

Comment: but in the project which I working on there is more than 30 controllers already.

Comment: Is there other solution?

Comment: I think you can try echo current_url();

Comment: But above method is very suitable for long terms. I create this way only in my every projects.

Comment: that is right you. that is very beautiful MVC. but in the project I working on we load so many models in one controller. eg: we named controller order and we order_model, other1_model also as needed.

Comment: in our project that is the best practice to pass the value that filter something like status to the uri. so the link should be look like this dir_name/controller_name/function_name/some_param

Comment: you can visits here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Comment: I have updated my answer can you please look into it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155385/discussion-between-test-test-and-chaitanya-desai).

Comment: yes I get it, in the model I used LIKE STATEMENT to like three thing: class name, method name, and dir name. I hope it work well. thx for your help @Chaitanya Desai

Comment: $this->router->directory;
$this->router->class;
$this->router->method;

Comment: they are also property to return the class name, method name, and directory name